# Why does refreshing localhost send/log two requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'll construct the following basic example that abstracts away a bunch of implementation details of my program to convey the core question. Let's say I have:

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("request event");
    res.end("Hello World");
});
server.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(server.listening); // true
    console.log("Server listening on port: 5000...");
});
```

Obviously my terminal shows Server listening on port: 5000..., but every time I refresh my browser I get two "request event" instances logged. I've had this happen a lot of times in the past and never really bothered with it, but why does this happen?

Comment: Ist it really res.end() on line 5? Or ist this a typo and it's res.send("Hello World")?

Comment: From memory the first request is to fetch the favicon and the second one is the actual request. Or maybe it is the other way around. log the request object and send the output to a file and have a look

Comment: @Huegelkoenig it's as written

Comment: @DavePile That's right, I believe the second request is the favicon fetch request. I totally forgot. Deja vu

Comment: @DavePile By the way, what's the best way to log the request object to a file? It has to be a string and obviously I can't just toString() the object or it'll become [object Object].

Comment: For a one off like this just log it ` console.log("request event: ", req);` and then redirect the output from the command line `node index.js > out.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, browsers by default requests for favicon.ico.
That's why you see two request event.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are always two requests that by default browser requests.

- One is the blank HTML page request. This loads the HTML page and then gets rendered by the browser.
- Second is the icon (Also known as favicon.ico) that you see beside a tab. Now if your page has a link to this icon, the browser will load otherwise will fail to load.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url)
    console.log("request event");
    res.end("Hello World");
});


server.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(server.listening); // true
    console.log("Server listening on port: 5000...");
});
```

One for your request and one for favicon.ico sent by default from browser